# "Bogus in bogus" meaning

Tags: etymology, phrase-meaning

What does this phrase mean? The context is from the play [No Exit](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ZhzzCQAAQBAJ&pg=PT11&dq=%22And,+to+tell+the+truth,+I+had+quite+a+habit+of+living+among+furniture+that%22+no+exit&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiL1N_K69HZAhVYHGMKHVTKCcAQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22And%2C%20to%20tell%20the%20truth%2C%20I%20had%20quite%20a%20habit%20of%20living%20among%20furniture%20that%22%20no%20exit&f=false) by Jean-Paul:

> And,  to tell  the  truth,  I  had quite  a  habit  of  living  among  furniture  that  I  didn't relish, and in false  positions.  I'd  even come  to like  it. A  false  position in a  LOUIS-Philippe dining-room—you know  the  style?—well, that  had its  points,  you know.  Bogus  in  bogus, so to speak.

In addition, I would really appreciate if anyone could explain the meaning of whole paragraph.

Answer (score -2):

You're almost asking for literary criticism, which belongs somewhere else.

Still, the passage is a deliberate construct, designed to support the conclusion "Bogus in bogus"

"I had quite a habit of living among furniture that I didn't relish…" is loosely to say, "bogus" living.

"… in false positions" is loosely to say both the same and "a LOUIS-Philippe dining-room" is false.

"Bogus in bogus" cleverly, so to speak, combines the two.